# Desativar campo ao clicar no checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como faço para desabilitar um campo ao clicar na opção checkbox?

Comment: Podes explicar melhor a pergunta e juntar HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um exemplo simples para fazer o que deseja:

```js
$('#control').on('change', function () {
  $('#target').prop('disabled', $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="control" />
<input type="text" id="target" />
```

**Nota:** A biblioteca [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/) foi utilizada.

Comment: Obrigado Luiz, eu havia conseguido somente fazer o inverso.